# Google Maps API error: MissingKeyMapError

Tags: javascript, html, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I'm getting this error **only** in the web hosted version of my website and **I'm using the Key**, It works fine in local!
Help please!

```
<script async src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?=AIzaSyDudFyTGhbU2CvJtJNxdfkPcJfRQnZ1pbTg&libraries=geometry">
```

Comment: you're using the key.....how (code would be helpful to give an answer)?

Comment: voila! take a look

Comment: it should be `?key=` instead of `?=`

Comment: It works ,Thank you !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the API key is  not being assigned because you are missing the GET parameter key in the url, in this case '?key='

```
<script async src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyDudFyTGhbU2CvJtJNxdfkPcJfRQnZ1pbTg&libraries=geometry">
```

If it still doesn't work, check out this guide from Google: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/get-api-key