# angular google maps api key not getting passed

Tags: javascript, angularjs, api, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am trying to use Angular google maps and I went through the quick setup supplied by angular google maps

```
    .config(['$routeProvider','$locationProvider','uiGmapGoogleMapApiProvider,
        function($routeProvider,$locationProvider,uiGmapGoogleMapApiProvider) {
           // Other configurations
          uiGmapGoogleMapApiProvider.configure({
            key: ‘MY_GOOGLE_API_KEY’,
            v: ‘3.17’,
            libraries: 'weather,geometry,visualization'
          });
        }
    ]);
```

I setup an API key in Google API Console, but when I load the page i get an MissingKeyMapError.

> Google Maps API error: MissingKeyMapError https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/error-messages#missing-key-map-error

I have the Google Javascript API enabled in the API console.  I am at a loss as to what I am doing wrong.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I hope the single quotes on these two line (             key: ‘API_KEY’,
            v: ‘3.17’, ) is correct ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved the issue.  Turns out I was loading the Google Maps API v3 twice.  I was loading it in the provider

`uiGmapGoogleMapApi.then(function(maps) {});`

and loading the script tag

`<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js"></script>`

Once I removed the script tag, It worked!

Thanks for everyones help.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you used a key parameter with a valid API key. Follow this [link](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/get-api-key#get-an-api-key) for the steps on how to get the proper API Key for your project.

> 1. Go to the [Google API Console](https://console.developers.google.com/flows/enableapi?apiid=maps_backend,geocoding_backend,directions_backend,distance_matrix_backend,elevation_backend,places_backend&keyType=CLIENT_SIDE&reusekey=true).
> 2. Create or select a project.
> 3. Click **Continue** to enable the API and any related services.
> 4. On the **Credentials** page, get a **Browser key** (and set the API Credentials).  Note: If you have an existing **Browser key**, you may
>      use that key.
> 5. To prevent quota theft, [secure your API key following these best practices](https://support.google.com/cloud/answer/6310037).
> 6. (Optional) Enable billing. See [Usage Limits](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/usage)
>      for more information.

But based from this [thread](https://github.com/angular-ui/angular-google-maps/issues/1889), the problem was because of a stray script tag which was including the google maps api before using this library. You can also check this related [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38517094/google-maps-api-error-missingkeymaperror).

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions @abielita, but it is still not working.  I looked at the links you suggested and everything checked out.  I don't get the error when the api key is in the query string
`https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=MY_API_KEY`
The map isn't showing up, but I'm not getting the previuos error.   I will have to figure that one out.